# Mac - Getting audio devices vendor-ID and product-id and adjust it the uid I get from CoreAudio

Tags: macos

I am building a list of the OSX audio devices.
I am using CoreAudio for getting the list
and I would like also to get the vendor-id and product-id for each one of them.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to first look up the audio device in the I/O registry and get the VID/PID from there, as it was [outlined a while ago on the CoreAudio mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Jul/msg00140.html):

```c
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/audio/IOAudioDefines.h>
#include <IOKit/usb/USB.h>

AudioDeviceID deviceID = ...

// get device UID for AudioDevice ID
AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput, 0};
UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
CFStringRef uid = NULL;
OSStatus err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &address, 0, NULL, &size, &uid);

NSNumber *vid, *pid;

// find matching IOAudioEngine object
io_iterator_t it;
if (IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching(kIOAudioEngineClassName), &it) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
    io_service_t service;
    while ((service = IOIteratorNext(it)) != 0) {
        CFStringRef uniqueID = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, CFSTR(kIOAudioEngineGlobalUniqueIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        if (uniqueID && CFEqual(uniqueID, uid)) {
            vid = CFBridgingRelease(IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, CFSTR(kUSBVendorID), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0));
            pid = CFBridgingRelease(IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, CFSTR(kUSBProductID), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0));
        }
        CFRelease(uniqueID);
        if (vid || pid) break;
    }
    IOObjectRelease(it);
}
```

The same technique can also be used to get other USB properties of the audio device like the USB location ID (`kUSBDevicePropertyLocationID`), e.g. to correlate audio with CoreMIDI devices.

Comment: Good for get locationID `kUSBDevicePropertyLocationID`

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector = kAudioDevicePropertyModelUID 
This will contain both vid and pid and you will be able to extract it from there

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
kAudioDevicePropertyModelUID, 
kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, 
kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};

And query for the property data using: AudioObjectGetPropertyData
```